Howe to get the proportion for each class in pandas dataframe
I am working on a dataFrame sv, it looks like this
print(sv)
            count
 Severity        
  2         398142
  3          84520
  4          13064
  1           4274

The 'Severity' is index's name, and the values saved in 'count' feature.
I am trying to use the index's name to get the proportion for each level, my code is like this:
 sv_rt = sv / sum(sv["Severity"]) * 100
 print(sv_rt)

However, it returns KeyError: 'Severity'. How should I fix this code, I suppose it should be quite simple. Thanks for your help.

You're not far, you have to sum the Series/DataFrame:
sv_rt = sv / sv.sum() * 100

Output:
            count
Severity         
2         79.6284
3         16.9040
4          2.6128
1          0.8548

Note that if you obtained sv with value_counts, you could obtain the normalized version directly with normalize=True.
sv_rt = original_df['Severity'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100)

